# crash report using optimization other than -o0 after xcode 4.5 update

Tags: iphone, compiler-optimization, crash-reports, pjsip, xcode4.5

I've updated to Xcode 4.5 today and I can't produce a functional release build of my app any longer.  I had no trouble producing a release with the previous version of Xcode.

I noticed that it doesn't crash when I run it directly on my phone in debug (-O0), but when I produce a release (-Os) it crashes consistently a few seconds after startup.

I can also produce a working release if I set pjsua_app.c to -O0 while leaving the rest of the project at the release default of -Os.

Below is a crash log using the setting "Fast [-O, O1]":

```
Incident Identifier: DB1C14AD-5C2A-4F2C-8B03-E483A7D31760
CrashReporter Key:   435140979595045aaa5a1c90fee1a20f6faf280a
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         myAppName [14144]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/CD2A07F5-3E72-444D-9BD9-910E4634C4EC/myAppName.app/myAppName
Identifier:      myAppName
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-09-19 23:41:39.098 -0600
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361f532c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d41208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d3a316 __abort + 86
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d2c3c4 __stack_chk_fail + 164
4   myAppName                       0x000ce0dc pjsip_init (pjsua_app.c:4391)
5   myAppName                       0x0008e9d2 general_callsystem_init (general_call.m:149)
6   myAppName                       0x00084b4c -[MainsipphoneAppDelegate initPjsip] (MainsipphoneAppDelegate.m:578)
7   myAppName                       0x0009f3ec -[LoginViewController ProvisionServerGotResult:provision_array:] (LoginViewController.m:1530)
8   myAppName                       0x000ab88e -[ProvisionServer parserDidEndDocument:] (ProvisionServer.m:993)
9   Foundation                      0x354698e0 _endDocument + 68
10  libxml2.2.dylib                 0x3663fb88 xmlParseChunk + 4364
11  Foundation                      0x3546895e -[NSXMLParser parse] + 510
12  myAppName                       0x000a765e -[ProvisionServer ParseXMLFileAtURL:] (ProvisionServer.m:188)
13  myAppName                       0x000a7502 -[ProvisionServer connectionDidFinishLoading:] (ProvisionServer.m:157)
14  Foundation                      0x35484c22 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 10
15  Foundation                      0x353dc6d2 -[NSURLConnectionInternalConnection invokeForDelegate:] + 22
16  Foundation                      0x353dc69c -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 192
17  Foundation                      0x353dc5be -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 54
18  CFNetwork                       0x351417ee URLConnectionClient::_clientDidFinishLoading(URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue*) + 186
19  CFNetwork                       0x3513649e URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload(XConnectionEventInfo<XClientEvent, XClientEventParams>*, long) + 418
20  CFNetwork                       0x3513619c URLConnectionClient::processEvents() + 100
21  CFNetwork                       0x351360d2 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 150
22  CoreFoundation                  0x35913acc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 8
23  CoreFoundation                  0x35913298 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3591203e __CFRunLoopRun + 646
25  CoreFoundation                  0x3589549e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
26  CoreFoundation                  0x35895366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
27  GraphicsServices                0x37531432 GSEventRunModal + 130
28  UIKit                           0x333a1cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
29  myAppName                       0x00081a78 main (main.m:14)
30  myAppName                       0x00081a30 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361e53a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x347cff04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x347cfc22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361f5cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cfcf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cfccc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361e5004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361e51fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x359133ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35912124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3589549e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35895366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x31794c9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d0272e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d025e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361f5cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cfcf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cfccc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361f5cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cfcf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cfccc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361e5004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361e51fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x359133ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35912124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3589549e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35895366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x353cebb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x353cea7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x3546258a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d0272e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d025e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361f5cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cfcf36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cfccc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361f5570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3591763a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d0272e _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d025e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361f5628 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d06b1a nanosleep + 138
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d06a84 usleep + 44
3   myAppName                       0x0013f3c2 pj_thread_sleep + 18
4   myAppName                       0x0013e342 pj_ioqueue_poll + 94
5   myAppName                       0x0011760a worker_proc + 42
6   myAppName                       0x0013f2b6 thread_main + 58
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d0272e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d025e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361f5628 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d06b1a nanosleep + 138
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d06a84 usleep + 44
3   myAppName                       0x0013f3c2 pj_thread_sleep + 18
4   myAppName                       0x0013e342 pj_ioqueue_poll + 94
5   myAppName                       0x00102540 pjsip_endpt_handle_events2 + 124
6   myAppName                       0x000e434c worker_thread + 56
7   myAppName                       0x0013f2b6 thread_main + 58
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d0272e _pthread_start + 314
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32d025e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ef4cd98      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x2fe7d724
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x5d5c3434     r10: 0x0f68cfb0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fe7d718      lr: 0x32d4120f      pc: 0x361f532c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0x80000 -   0x1a8fff +myAppName armv7  <f7f3371d762c361a9a632fafedfa3011> /var/mobile/Applications/CD2A07F5-3E72-444D-9BD9-910E4634C4EC/myAppName.app/myAppName
0x2fe7f000 - 0x2fea0fff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30687000 - 0x3068dfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x30761000 - 0x30886fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x308c0000 - 0x308c6fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x30949000 - 0x3095efff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x30a70000 - 0x30a73fff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x30a74000 - 0x30abcfff  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x30af8000 - 0x3103cfff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x316eb000 - 0x31eaafff  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x31ebd000 - 0x31f95fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x31f96000 - 0x3217afff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3217b000 - 0x321c5fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x321ed000 - 0x32203fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3220f000 - 0x323ccfff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x32545000 - 0x32556fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x32769000 - 0x3285afff  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3286d000 - 0x32870fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x328e1000 - 0x3291dfff  IMFoundation armv7  <253125b9103c3d13b66923ac6893c25b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x3294a000 - 0x3296afff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x329c7000 - 0x329d3fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x329d4000 - 0x329f7fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x32aa9000 - 0x32af3fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x32b0e000 - 0x32b14fff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x32b17000 - 0x32b1bfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32b1c000 - 0x32b1dfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x32b1e000 - 0x32b1ffff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x32b2e000 - 0x32b30fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x32c9e000 - 0x32ccafff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x32ccb000 - 0x32ceffff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x32cf4000 - 0x32d80fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x32df7000 - 0x32e08fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x32e86000 - 0x32e87fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x32e88000 - 0x32e8bfff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x32e8c000 - 0x32f32fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x32f73000 - 0x32faefff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33370000 - 0x33812fff  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33968000 - 0x339adfff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x339ec000 - 0x339f1fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x33a33000 - 0x33a90fff  StoreServices armv7  <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x33c2b000 - 0x33c74fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x33db7000 - 0x33dbdfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x33ea3000 - 0x33eadfff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x34263000 - 0x34272fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x34273000 - 0x34278fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3427f000 - 0x34289fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3431a000 - 0x3431efff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x34363000 - 0x34388fff  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x343c4000 - 0x343dafff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x34431000 - 0x3446ffff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x345e0000 - 0x34729fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3472a000 - 0x3472afff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3472b000 - 0x34736fff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x34752000 - 0x34789fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x347c7000 - 0x347cbfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x347cc000 - 0x347e2fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3480a000 - 0x3485bfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3485c000 - 0x34863fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3492e000 - 0x3492ffff  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x34951000 - 0x3495dfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3498f000 - 0x34997fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x34998000 - 0x3499cfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x34b27000 - 0x34b3bfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34f0c000 - 0x34f50fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x34f82000 - 0x34f8ffff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x35132000 - 0x35209fff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3520a000 - 0x35289fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x35368000 - 0x3536cfff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x353be000 - 0x3553cfff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x35618000 - 0x356e8fff  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x35768000 - 0x3581efff  AVFoundation armv7  <35cb7a0eb1dc3554a777c1cc11cb0415> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x3581f000 - 0x35825fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x35829000 - 0x35872fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x35873000 - 0x35876fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x35886000 - 0x3599dfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x35b28000 - 0x35b80fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x35b83000 - 0x35b83fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x35b8c000 - 0x35b9bfff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x35b9c000 - 0x35b9cfff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x35b9f000 - 0x35baefff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x35cf1000 - 0x35cf8fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x35d1f000 - 0x35d6bfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x35dee000 - 0x35e98fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x35eba000 - 0x35ebdfff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x35eda000 - 0x35eddfff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x35ee4000 - 0x36029fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3602a000 - 0x36036fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x36037000 - 0x3606ffff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x36070000 - 0x36086fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x36160000 - 0x361d4fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x361e4000 - 0x361fafff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3622f000 - 0x36237fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x36238000 - 0x3623dfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <dc11c5c2cbe73a6288a6094ebf5de673> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x36240000 - 0x36240fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x36415000 - 0x36415fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x36421000 - 0x3650ffff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3655f000 - 0x36560fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x365d8000 - 0x365f1fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3662a000 - 0x366d7fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x366f0000 - 0x36733fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x36734000 - 0x36735fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3676c000 - 0x36770fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x3678e000 - 0x36792fff  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x36795000 - 0x369c2fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <c3098478486032c6aff336fa711c4fc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x369c6000 - 0x369c7fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x36a0b000 - 0x36a84fff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x36a85000 - 0x36aa4fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x36aa5000 - 0x36b08fff  IMCore armv7  <046b6b615a743057b59d4aaba8a91d61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x36b0e000 - 0x36b4afff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x36fe9000 - 0x36fedfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x36fee000 - 0x3705efff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x3752d000 - 0x37537fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3768c000 - 0x3794dfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x379fb000 - 0x379fdfff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x37a06000 - 0x37a3bfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x37a4a000 - 0x37ad0fff  CoreMotion armv7  <6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x37ad1000 - 0x37b11fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x37cdd000 - 0x37da3fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x37de0000 - 0x37e2efff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x37e7d000 - 0x37e7dfff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x37e7e000 - 0x37e9bfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x37ee0000 - 0x37ee9fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x37f59000 - 0x37f59fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x37f7b000 - 0x37fccfff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x37fcd000 - 0x3800afff  FTServices armv7  <3f23418319a03a589dd5cac7df20e238> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x3816b000 - 0x3822dfff  Celestial armv7  <19617260ee073e23b95e456d93930aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
```

Here is pjsip_init() (line 4391 is the last line: "return 1;"):

```
    int pjsip_init(const char *logfile, const char *stunserver, const char *proxy, const char *outboundproxy)
{
    static char buf[256], buf1[256], buf2[256], buf3[256];
    int param_num = 0;

    buf[0] = buf1[0] = buf2[0] = buf3[0] = 0;

    sprintf(buf, "--log-file=%s", logfile);
    if(stunserver!=NULL && *stunserver != '\0') {
        param_num++;
        sprintf(buf1, "--stun-srv=%s", stunserver);
    }
    if(proxy!=NULL && *proxy != '\0') {
        param_num++;
        sprintf(buf2, "--proxy=%s", proxy);
    }
    if(outboundproxy!=NULL && *outboundproxy != '\0') {
        param_num++;
        sprintf(buf3, "--outbound=%s", outboundproxy);
    }

    {
        char *argv[param_num + 3];
        int pos = 3;
        argv[0] = "sipapp";
        argv[1] = "--log-level=4";
        argv[2] = "--app-log-level=4";
        if(buf[0] != 0) 
            argv[pos++] = buf;
        if(buf1[0] != 0)
            argv[pos++] = buf1;
        if(buf2[0] != 0)
            argv[pos++] = buf2;
        if(buf3[0] != 0)
            argv[pos++] = buf3;
        app_init(pos, argv);
    }
    /*
     if(wstunserver) {                                      
     char *argv[] = {"sipapp",  "--log-level=4", "--app-log-level=4",buf, buf1};
     argv[0] = buf;
     app_init(5, argv);
     } else {
     char *argv[] = {"sipapp",  "--log-level=4", "--app-log-level=4",buf};
     argv[0] = buf;
     app_init(4, argv);
     }
     */
    pjsua_start();
    return 1;
}
```

Can anyone help me diagnose this crash log?

Is anyone experiencing anything similar after upgrading to Xcode 4.5?

Comment: Is this with the straight LLVM Compiler or with LLVM GCC? Which version of Xcode did you use previously? This looks like stack corruption, as discussed here: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/298775-stack-chk-fail.html

Comment: The Build Setting for Compiler is set to "Default compiler" which corresponds to Apple LLVM 4.1.  I previously compiled on Xcode 4.4.1.

Comment: I thought compiling with LLVM GCC 4.2 made the problem go away, but it actually just changed the problem to a different crash.  As stated above, compiling with no optimizations on pjsua_app.c seems to be working so far though.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's a fencepost error on the stack in pjsua_start() or something it calls which leaves the stack mangled when pjsip_init() attempts to return.

Look at the stack pointer, and the contents at the stack pointer, before and after the call to  pjsua_start().  On the simulator, this will be the %esp register. (In gdb, you can use "inspect %esp" to show the value or use the register window.)

Answer (score 0):

You can user [Crittercism SDK](https://www.crittercism.com/developers/docs) which will send the the crash logs and replorts directly to your mail id.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem. 
In my case i converted my project to use ARC.
This is how i fixed the bug:

The crash comes up when i change the optimization to fastest in release.
I change the optimization in debug mode same as release (fastest) to test.
then i got same crash in debug. 
Debugger shows me the file where it crash. 
Then i remove arc implementation from that (library) file.

one more thing, I change build config, use arc to NO & put compiler flag to -fno-objc-arc where ARC is not used and -fobjc-arc where ARC is used.